# ByRef argument type mismatch:

Tags: excel, excel-addins, byref, vba

ByRef argument type mismatch when running the fileconv.xla add-in in Excel 97.

The reason I need this to work is because I need to convert ~100 Lotus 1-2-3 files from wk* to xls.

The term highlighted in VBA when I compile is marked by double asteriks in the separated code:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathFile(**p_FileInfo**(i, 3), p_FileInfo(i, 4)), ReadOnly:=True, Password:="password"
```

```vba
Sub FinishSub()


Dim TestOpen As Boolean
Dim DirDest As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
CreateDir "wzkfpbdxwzkfpbdxwzkfpbdx"
If Not (DirCreated) Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
End If

If Len(dlg.DropDowns("DriveDD").List(dlg.DropDowns("DriveDD").ListIndex)) <> 2 Then
    DirDest = Right(dlg.DropDowns("DriveDD").List(dlg.DropDowns("DriveDD").ListIndex), _
                Len(dlg.DropDowns("DriveDD").List(dlg.DropDowns("DriveDD").ListIndex)) - 3) & _
                Right(FullPath, Len(FullPath) - 2)
Else
    DirDest = dlg.DropDowns("DriveDD").List(dlg.DropDowns("DriveDD").ListIndex) & _
                Right(FullPath, Len(FullPath) - 2)
End If

Set wbResult = Workbooks.Add
ActiveCell.Value = LookupString("File")
Range("B1").Value = LookupString("ConvertedTo")
Range("C1").Value = LookupString("Result")
Range("D1").Value = LookupString("Reason")
Range("A2").Select

k = 0
For i = 1 To CountFile
    p_FileInfo(i, 5) = DirDest
    If p_FileInfo(i, 7) = "yes" Then
        k = k + 1
        On Error GoTo ErrorOpen
            Success = "True"
            ErrorMsg = ""
            SetWaitCursor True
            If TestIfWorkbookIsOpen(p_FileInfo(i, 4)) Then Workbooks(p_FileInfo(i, 4)).Close saveChanges:=False
            Application.StatusBar = LookupString("Opening") & p_FileInfo(i, 4) & "(" & k & "/" & CountFileToConvert & ")"
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False


            Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathFile(**p_FileInfo**(i, 3), p_FileInfo(i, 4)), ReadOnly:=True, Password:="password"



        On Error GoTo 0
        On Error Resume Next
            Application.StatusBar = LookupString("Saving") & p_FileInfo(i, 6) & "(" & k & "/" & CountFileToConvert & ")"
            ' Check if the XLS filename already exists.
            FindFileName
            Workbooks(p_FileInfo(i, 4)).SaveAs Filename:=PathFile(p_FileInfo(i, 5), p_FileInfo(i, 6)), FileFormat:=xlNormal
            'Application.StatusBar = False
            Workbooks(p_FileInfo(i, 4)).Close saveChanges:=False
            Workbooks(p_FileInfo(i, 6)).Close saveChanges:=False
            SaveIsSuccess Success
            SetWaitCursor False
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next i
SaveIsSuccess "End"
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

ErrorOpen:   ' Error-handling routine.
Select Case Err ' Evaluate Error Number.
    Case 18
        TestMsgBox = MsgBox(LookupString("UserInterruption", "AlertTable"), vbYesNo)
        If TestMsgBox = vbYes Then
            On Error Resume Next
                Application.StatusBar = False
                Workbooks(p_FileInfo(i, 4)).Close saveChanges:=False
                Workbooks(p_FileInfo(i, 6)).Close saveChanges:=False
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Exit Sub
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            Resume Next
        End If
    Case 1004
        SetWaitCursor False
        Set dlg = ThisWorkbook.DialogSheets("Password")
        dlg.DialogFrame.Characters.Text = p_FileInfo(i, 4)
        If TryAgain = False Then
            dlg.TextBoxes("PassTB").Text = LookupString("IsProtected", "AlertTable")
            dlg.EditBoxes("PassEB").Text = ""
        Else
            dlg.TextBoxes("PassTB").Text = LookupString("InvalidPassword", "AlertTable")
        End If
        ShowTest = dlg.Show
        Select Case ShowTest
            Case True
                Resume
            Case False
                Success = "False"
                ErrorMsg = Error()
                Resume Next
        End Select
        SetWaitCursor True
        End Select
  Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, try to isolate what part of your code is that you asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have this

```
Public Function PathFile(ByRef a As String, ByRef b As String)
PathFile = "C:\Bla.txt"
End Function
```

and `p_FileInfo` is an Array, so in this case you have to call the function like this:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathFile(CStr(p_FileInfo(i, 3)), CStr(p_FileInfo(i, 4))), ReadOnly:=True, Password:="password"
```

That should work if I am not misunderstand your question.